# How to setup PostgreSQL with Visual Studio 2017 or .NET 4.5+?

Tags: .net, postgresql, visual-studio, entity-framework, npgsql

There are several posts and articles related to the installation of PostgreSQL, but they are a bit confusing and provides different approaches for different versions.

This post will help those wanting to use *PostgreSQL* with *Entity framework - Database first approach*.

Requirements : 
VS 2017
PostgreSQL DB 11.1
EF 6+

Comment: The update info on this is here https://www.npgsql.org/doc/installation.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**STEP 1 :**

Install [latest](https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers.jsp/) version of PostgreSQL v-11.1 (did not try-out lower version)

**STEP 2 :**

Install npgsql .NET connector (highlighted in below image) by using the stack builder tool. [ Find it inside - ..\PostgreSQL\11\bin\stackbuilder.exe ]

[image]

**STEP 3 :**

Go to environment variable, modify ***path*** under ***System Variables*** and add lib and bin folder paths of PostgreSQL

- [Installed Drive]:\...\PostgreSQL\11\bin
- [Installed Drive]:\...\PostgreSQL\11\lib

**STEP 4 :**

***Important!*** Download and install [Npgsql.vsix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration) extension for Visual Studio (Needed for Data Source wizard to provide you PostgreSQL as an option, when you want to assign connection to Entity Framework for DB access)

**STEP 5 :**

Create a new project. For EF 6+, add the following Nuget package -> EntityFramework6.Npgsql

*Note : the above package will download the required dependencies for you*

**STEP 6 :**

Add Entity Framework model and related connection settings to config file.

Finally add the below code snippet to config file :

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

***SIDE NOTE :*** *No need for installing npgsql dll separately in GAC or VS assemblies as suggested in some articles, because the new version does this for you.*